# How do I create a page without a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on an app which has many 'Activities'. Each 'Activity' has many 'Ranks'. I'd like each 'Activity' to have a page called grading, where the user can see a list of all of that activity's ranks and conveniently update them. I imagine the URL would be something like http://localhost:3000/activities/21/grading

I'm already using http://localhost:3000/activities/21/edit for its intended purpose.

I don't need a model for gradings, as I don't need to save any grading records.

I know exactly what to put in the view, I'm just unsure what to add to the controller and routes files. Other people have worked on this app but I'm unable to contact them.

Routes

```rb
    resources :activities do
        collection do
            get 'scheduled_classes'
        end
    end
    resources :ranks
end
```

activities_controller

```rb
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @activity = Activity.new
        @activity.timeslots.build
        @activity.ranks.build
    end

    def create
        @activity = current_club.activities.new(activity_params)
        if @activity.save
            flash[:success] = "New class created!"
            redirect_to activity_path(@activity)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @activity = current_club.activities.find_by(id: params[:id])
        @active_ranks = @activity.ranks.where(active: true)
        if !@activity.active?
            redirect_to activities_path
        else
            @activity.timeslots.build
        end
    end

    def update
        @activity = current_club.activities.find_by(id: params[:id])
        if @activity.update_attributes(activity_params)
            flash[:success] = "Class updated!"
            redirect_to edit_activity_path(@activity)
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def show
        @activity = current_club.activities.find_by(id: params[:id])
        @active_ranks = @activity.ranks.where(active: true)
        if @activity.nil?
            redirect_to root_url
        elsif !@activity.active?
            redirect_to activities_path
        end 
    end

    def index
        @activities = current_club.activities.all 
    end

    def destroy
        @activity = current_club.activities.find_by(id: params[:id])
        if @activity.nil?
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            @activity.destroy
            flash[:success] = "Class deleted"
            redirect_to activities_path
        end
    end
end

    private

        def activity_params
            params.require(:activity).permit(:name, :active, 
                                             :timeslots_attributes => [:id,
                                                                       :time_start,
                                                                       :time_end,
                                                                       :day,
                                                                       :active,
                                                                       :schedule],
                                             :ranks_attributes => [:id,
                                                                   :name,
                                                                   :position,
                                                                   :active])
        end

end
```

activity

```rb
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :club
  has_many :timeslots, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :timeslots,:allow_destroy => true
  has_many :ranks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :attendances, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ranks
  validates :club_id, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes don't need to have an associated model or resource.

```
  resources :activities do
    collection do
        get 'scheduled_classes'
    end
    member do
      get :grading
    end 
  end
```

will match to `activities#grading`

See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes for more info.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to add a route on a particular activity, you should add member route on the activity like below,

```
resources :activities do
    collection do
        get 'scheduled_classes'
    end
    get :grading, on: :member
end
```

Apart from this, you have to add method in `ActivitiesController` for this route like below,

```
def grading
  @activity = Activity.find_by(id: params[:id])
  # do more here
end
```

In view files, you can create `grading.html.erb` under activities resources and put your view code there.